# Invalid use of flexible array member (Not as the others)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, flexible-array-member

So I have these 2 structures:

```
typedef struct item { 
    const char *label;
    int value;
} Item;

typedef struct item_coll { 
    size_t length; 
    Item items[]; 
} ItemColl;
```

And I want to do this:

```
 int main() {

    Item a = {"A", 10};
    Item b = {"B", 20};
    Item c = {"C", 30};

    Item items[] = {a, b, c};

    size_t length = sizeof(items)/sizeof(items[0]);

    ItemColl *column = malloc (sizeof(column) + length * sizeof(Item));

    column -> length = length;
    column -> items = items;

    printf("%ld\n", column -> length);

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting the error "Invalid use of flexible array member" here:

```
column -> items = items;
```

As far as I know, I'm allocating the needed space, which is why I don't understand what the problem is.

I've seen 2 more posts with this title but none of them solves my problem, as I've tried the answers to those questions.

Comment: You cannot assign one array to another using `=` - flexible array member or otherwise

Comment: Aside: did you mean `sizeof(*collumn)`? You are getting the size of a pointer.

Comment: You either need a `memcpy` or `for (int idx = 0;  idx < length;  ++idx) collumn->items[idx] = items[idx];` instead of `collumn->items = items;`

Comment: Thanks a lot @CraigEstey. That worked. Make an answer with that so I can mark it.

Comment: `sizeof(collumn)` is just the size of a pointer, you need to use `sizeof *collumn` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can't assign one array to another.

Partly, because the compiler can't always know how long the array is, particularly for a flexible array member. (e.g.) Also, either the source or target might be a pointer. To be consistent, it just flags it.

So, change:

```
column->items = items;
```

to:

```
for (int idx = 0;  idx < length;  ++idx)
    column->items[idx] = items[idx];
```

Or, to use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(column->items, items, sizeof(column->items[0]) * length);
```

---

*Side note:*

If `column->items` were a *pointer* (e.g. `Item *items`) instead, doing:

```
column->items = items;
```

*would* be valid. But, it would *not* copy the *values*. It would just set the struct's pointer to the address of the function scoped array `items`. This would not be the desired result.

Comment: @miquelini don't forget to correct the `sizeof` error.

Comment: `memcpy(collumn->items,items,sizeof collumn->items[0] * length);` has an advantage over `memcpy(...,...,sizeof(Item) ...);`, it is easier to reivew and remains correct should the type of `.items` change.